# How to convert Mongo query in to java object

Tags: java, mongodb

I have `Mongo` query that I executed using NoSqlBooster(Tool) and getting expected out put. How can I convert same query in `Java` object.

This is `Mongo` Query :

```
db.revenue.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        hotelId: "122"
        sessionId: "dgd"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
             date: "$date",
             serviceOrFacilty: "$serviceOrFacilty"
         },
         "SUM(orderTotalAmount)":{
              $sum: "$orderTotalAmount"
         },
         "SUM(grandTotalAmount)":{
              $sum: "$grandTotalAmount"
         },
      }
},   {
      $project: {
          date: "$_id.date",
          serviceOrFacilty: "$_id.serviceOrFacilty",
          "SUM(orderTotalAmount)": "$SUM(orderTotalAmount)",
          "SUM(grandTotalAmount)": "$SUM(grandTotalAmount)"
      }
}])
```

And this is my entity/data base classs

```
public class RevenueReportsTemporaryStorage {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field(value = FIELDS.SESSSION_ID)
    private String sessionId;
    @Field(value = FIELDS.HOTEL_ID)
    private String hotelId;
    @Field(value = FIELDS.DATE)
    private String date;
    @Field(value = FIELDS.SERVICE_OR_FACILITY)
    private String serviceOrFacility;
    @Field(value = FIELDS.CATEGORY)
    private String serviceCategory;
    @Field(value = FIELDS.USER_NAME)
    private String userName
    @Field(value = FIELDS.ORDER_TOTAL)
    private Double orderTotalAmount;
    @Field(value = FIELDS.ADJUSTMENT)
    private Double adjustmentAmount;
    @Field(value = FIELDS.DISCOUNT)
    private Double discount;
    @Field(value = FIELDS.TAX)
    private Map<String, Double> taxAmountWithHead;
    @Field(value = FIELDS.GRAND_TOTAL)
    private Double grandTotalAmount;
}
```

By using fields, how can write the query.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54952315/3432487

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert MongoDB query into Spring MongoDB syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951167/convert-mongodb-query-into-spring-mongodb-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where(FIELDS.HOTEL_ID).is(hotelId).and(FIELDS.SESSSION_ID).is(uniqueId)),
            group(FIELDS.DATE,FIELDS.SERVICE_OR_FACILITY).sum(FIELDS.ORDER_TOTAL).as(FIELDS.ORDER_TOTAL).sum(FIELDS.ADJUSTMENT)
                    .as(FIELDS.ADJUSTMENT).sum(FIELDS.DISCOUNT).as(FIELDS.DISCOUNT).sum(FIELDS.GRAND_TOTAL)
                    .as(FIELDS.GRAND_TOTAL),
            sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, previousOperation(),FIELDS.DATE,FIELDS.SERVICE_OR_FACILITY));
    AggregationResults<RevenueReportsTemporaryStorage> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,
            RevenueReportsTemporaryStorage.class, RevenueReportsTemporaryStorage.class);
    return groupResults.getMappedResults();
```