# How to use this mongoDb aggregation for C #

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I'm trying to make a specific query.
How can I use this same aggregation in mongoDb for C#?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "_id":1,
            "personalData":1,
            "Dependentsbenefits": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$Dependentsbenefits",
                    as: "depend",
                    cond:  { $eq: ["$$depend.dependentId", "70b39bed-e3e0-41e3-a5be-076623b9a909"] }
                }
            }
        }        
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using MongoDB compass tool.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54952315/3432487 for how to achieve the below result.

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
new BsonArray
{
    new BsonDocument("$project", 
    new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id", 1 }, 
            { "personalData", 1 }, 
            { "Dependentsbenefits", 
    new BsonDocument("$filter", 
    new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "input", "$Dependentsbenefits" }, 
                    { "as", "depend" }, 
                    { "cond", 
    new BsonDocument("$eq", 
    new BsonArray
                        {
                            "$$depend.dependentId",
                            "70b39bed-e3e0-41e3-a5be-076623b9a909"
                        }) }
                }) }
        })
}
```

Comment: How to use this data to query in Mongo using C #?

Comment: This is the c# code generated for your aggregation query.

Comment: I need an example of what a get would look like; _employee.Aggregate() + code above